# cloudControl automaticlly deletes Wordpress files

Tags: cloudcontrol

I successfully deployed my Wordpress app on cloudControl. However, I realised that whenever I upload an image, no matter how small, I dont get to see the image after some hours. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: You will need to provide more detail about what you are doing and how your server is configured to get any help here. Also provide any error messages you receive.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the non persitant file system. 
As described here:

https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#non-persistent-filesystem

For Wordpress you have to use a plugin which stores image files on a remote system like Amazon S3. For me it worked fine with

Amazon S3 for WordPress

By the way: the same for E-Mails you can use sendgrid with the sendgrid plugin.